# ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: python, base-de-datos, ms-access

Tengo esta query:

```
query_del = '''DELETE * FROM Students WHERE Students.[last_name] = "Q";'''
```

Y para ejecutarla hago lo siguiente:

```
conn= pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\XXX\Database.accdb;')

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(query)
```

Pero obtengo este error:

> ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

La database actualmente:

[image: Database]

Comment: Usas una variable diferente en `query_del` y `query`